# Does a Perl 6 module for rakudo exist to parse MIMEs?

Tags: email, mime, raku, rakudo

I searched github and modules.perl6.org but did not find a module to parse emails.

If there is no perl6 module yet a parrot module would be fine too.

Comment: I haven't tested these solutions but... The new [Perl 6 module Inline::Perl5](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5/blob/master/README.md) means most Perl 5 modules (including most of those on CPAN, including most of the ones using XS or C code etc.) are available. So you could presumably use [the Perl 5 Email::MIME module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::MIME). In addition [modules.perl6.org](http://modules.perl6.org/) includes a Perl 6 port of the Perl 5 Email::MIME module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that there isn't one. [The parrot runtime library](https://github.com/parrot/parrot/tree/master/runtime/parrot/library) doesn't seem to contain anything related either. You may want to add it to a [list of most wanted modules](https://github.com/perl6/ecosystem/wiki/Most-Wanted%3A-Modules-to-write-port)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Working through the RFCs i guess it will take more than an evening of work to get it right.